# Mootools JSONP issue

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm having ain issue getting JSONP to work.

I'm using the basic example:

```
alert('check 1');

var myJSONP = new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json',
    callbackKey: 'jsoncallback',
    data: {
        partTag: 'mtvo',
        iod: 'hlPrice',
        viewType: 'json',
        results: '100',
        query: 'ipod'
    },
    onRequest: function(url){
        // a script tag is created with a src attribute equal to url
    },
    onComplete: function(data){
        // the request was completed.
      alert('Done!')
    }
}).send();

alert('check 2');
```

But i never get an alert('Done') executed.

You can check it on codepen as well: http://codepen.io/r0b0tn1k/pen/VYZqeq

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request.JSONP is not part of the Core library, you can find it in More.

What you actually need is just to add this:

```
/*
---

script: Request.JSONP.js

name: Request.JSONP

description: Defines Request.JSONP, a class for cross domain javascript via script injection.

license: MIT-style license

authors:
  - Aaron Newton
  - Guillermo Rauch
  - Arian Stolwijk

requires:
  - Core/Element
  - Core/Request
  - MooTools.More

provides: [Request.JSONP]

...
*/

Request.JSONP = new Class({

    Implements: [Chain, Events, Options],

    options: {/*
        onRequest: function(src, scriptElement){},
        onComplete: function(data){},
        onSuccess: function(data){},
        onCancel: function(){},
        onTimeout: function(){},
        onError: function(){}, */
        onRequest: function(src){
            if (this.options.log && window.console && console.log){
                console.log('JSONP retrieving script with url:' + src);
            }
        },
        onError: function(src){
            if (this.options.log && window.console && console.warn){
                console.warn('JSONP '+ src +' will fail in Internet Explorer, which enforces a 2083 bytes length limit on URIs');
            }
        },
        url: '',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        injectScript: document.head,
        data: '',
        link: 'ignore',
        timeout: 0,
        log: false
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this.setOptions(options);
    },

    send: function(options){
        if (!Request.prototype.check.call(this, options)) return this;
        this.running = true;

        var type = typeOf(options);
        if (type == 'string' || type == 'element') options = {data: options};
        options = Object.merge(this.options, options || {});

        var data = options.data;
        switch (typeOf(data)){
            case 'element': data = document.id(data).toQueryString(); break;
            case 'object': case 'hash': data = Object.toQueryString(data);
        }

        var index = this.index = Request.JSONP.counter++;

        var src = options.url +
            (options.url.test('\\?') ? '&' :'?') +
            (options.callbackKey) +
            '=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_'+ index +
            (data ? '&' + data : '');

        if (src.length > 2083) this.fireEvent('error', src);

        Request.JSONP.request_map['request_' + index] = function(){
            this.success(arguments, index);
        }.bind(this);

        var script = this.getScript(src).inject(options.injectScript);
        this.fireEvent('request', [src, script]);

        if (options.timeout) this.timeout.delay(options.timeout, this);

        return this;
    },

    getScript: function(src){
        if (!this.script) this.script = new Element('script', {
            type: 'text/javascript',
            async: true,
            src: src
        });
        return this.script;
    },

    success: function(args, index){
        if (!this.running) return;
        this.clear()
            .fireEvent('complete', args).fireEvent('success', args)
            .callChain();
    },

    cancel: function(){
        if (this.running) this.clear().fireEvent('cancel');
        return this;
    },

    isRunning: function(){
        return !!this.running;
    },

    clear: function(){
        this.running = false;
        if (this.script){
            this.script.destroy();
            this.script = null;
        }
        return this;
    },

    timeout: function(){
        if (this.running){
            this.running = false;
            this.fireEvent('timeout', [this.script.get('src'), this.script]).fireEvent('failure').cancel();
        }
        return this;
    }

});

Request.JSONP.counter = 0;
Request.JSONP.request_map = {};
```

Works good after that.
http://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/JoPwvw

Comment: I figured that must be it, but in the examples on the official documentation it didnt list the dependencies...